# How to apply screen resize in BottomSheetDialogFragment?

Tags: android, bottomsheetdialogfragment

First, I will show you the BottomSheetDialogFragment class.

```
class BottomSheetReportFragment(var mContext: Context, var postId: String, var commentId: String?, var replyId: String?) : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    private lateinit var mView: View


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_report, container, false)

        return mView
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

        dialog.setOnShowListener { dialogInterface ->
            val bottomSheetDialog = dialogInterface as BottomSheetDialog
            setupRatio(bottomSheetDialog)
        }
        return dialog
    }

    private fun setupRatio(bottomSheetDialog: BottomSheetDialog) {
        val bottomSheet = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)

        val behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet!!)
        val layoutParam = bottomSheet.layoutParams as ViewGroup.LayoutParams

        layoutParam.height = getBottomSheetDialogDefaultHeight()
        bottomSheet.layoutParams = layoutParam
        behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
        behavior.peekHeight = getBottomSheetDialogDefaultHeight()
    }

    private fun getBottomSheetDialogDefaultHeight(): Int {
        return getWindowHeight() * 85 / 100
    }

    private fun getWindowHeight(): Int {
        val displayMetrics = mContext.resources.displayMetrics
        return displayMetrics.heightPixels
    }
}
```

xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:overScrollMode="never">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/first"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button_report"
                android:button="@null"
                android:paddingStart="14dp"
                android:paddingEnd="14dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#1C1C1C"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/second"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button_report"
                android:button="@null"
                android:paddingStart="14dp"
                android:paddingEnd="14dp"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="#1C1C1C"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/third"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button_report"
                android:button="@null"
                android:paddingStart="14dp"
                android:paddingEnd="14dp"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="#1C1C1C"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fourth"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button_report"
                android:button="@null"
                android:paddingStart="14dp"
                android:paddingEnd="14dp"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="#1C1C1C"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fifth"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button_report"
                android:button="@null"
                android:paddingStart="14dp"
                android:paddingEnd="14dp"
                android:text="5"
                android:textColor="#1C1C1C"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sixth"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button_report"
                android:button="@null"
                android:paddingStart="14dp"
                android:paddingEnd="14dp"
                android:text="6"
                android:textColor="#1C1C1C"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_edittext_comment"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="2"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="73dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#ADB1BA"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/input"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/input"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#CBCBCB"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

The Android keyboard is implemented so that any button from Button id `first` to `sixth` is pressed. But the problem here is that when the keyboard is up, the view focus is set on the EditText, but the EditText is obscured by the keyboard. Is there a way for BottomSheetDialogFragment to resize the view like Activity?

### [UPDATE]

For reference, the style is applied as follows.

1. adjustResize
2. stateAlwaysVisible
3. adjustResize, stateAlwaysVisible

I tried all three situations, but it didn't work.

```
<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize|stateAlwaysVisible</item>
</style>

<style name="AppModalStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/shape_bottom_sheet</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppBottomSheetDialogTheme`, add `android:windowSoftInputMode`.

```xml
<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme">
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
</style>
```